# Sitecore Desktop database selection shows non-existent database

Tags: configuration, sql-database

On my instance of Sitecore 8.2 Update 7, the database selection list in the lower right hand corner show two webs:

[image]

There is only one web in publishing targets:

[image]

And my connection strings only have one web databse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<connectionStrings>

<add name="core" connectionString="Data Source=myserver;Persist Security Info=False;Database=MyDatabase_Core;User Id=myuser;Password=*****" />
<add name="master" connectionString="Data Source=myserver;Persist Security Info=False;DatabaseMyDatabase_Master;User Id=myuser;Password=*****;" />
<add name="web" connectionString="Data Source=myserver;Persist Security Info=False;Database=MyDatabase_Web;User Id=myuser;Password=*****;" />

<!--(XDB -Powered by Sitecore Inc.) xDB Databases Connection Strings-->
<add name = "analytics" connectionString = "mymongo_dev_analytics_cloud1_cm"/>
<add name = "tracking.contact" connectionString = "mymongo_dev_tracking_contact_cloud1_cm"/>
<add name = "tracking.live" connectionString = "mymongo_dev_tracking_live_cloud1_cm"/>
<add name = "tracking.history" connectionString = "mymongo_dev_tracking_history_cloud1_cm"/>

<add name="reporting" connectionString="Data Source=myserver;Persist Security Info=False;Database=MyDatabase_Reporting;User Id=myuser;Password=*****;" />
<add name="session" connectionString="Data Source=myserver;Persist Security Info=False;Database=MyDatabase_Sessions;User Id=myuser;Password=*****;" />
<add name="custom" connectionString="Data Source=myserver;Persist Security Info=False;Database=MyDatabase_Custom;User Id=myuser;Password=*****;" />
<add name="custom-ef" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="TrustServerCertificate=False;Data Source=myserver;Database=MyDatabase_Custom;User Id=myuser;Password=*****;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Is this list stored as content somewhere? How can I clean it up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The databases which are shown in Database Selector on Sitecore Desktop are taken from the Sitecore configuration.

Open `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` and find there `<databases>` node directly under `<sitecore>` node. You will found there more than 1 databases with `id` attribute set to `web`.

```
<database id="core" singleInstance="true" type="Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel" patch:source="Sitecore.Buckets.config">
   ...
</database>
<database id="master" singleInstance="true" type="Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel" patch:source="Sitecore.Buckets.config">
   ...
</database>
<database id="web" singleInstance="true" type="Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel" patch:source="Sitecore.Buckets.config">
   ...
</database>
<!-- second web database -->
<database id="web" singleInstance="true" type="Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel" patch:source="Sitecore.Buckets.config">
   ...
</database>
```

Comment: Due to a badly configured patch, web was defined twice. Thanks.